# Wordpress JWPlayer Plugin how to EDIT the Playlist

Tags: wordpress, plugins, edit, jwplayer, playlist

I'm using WP `3.8.1` and JWPlayer Plugin 6 `2.1.2`. There i made new Playlists. But then how do i `edit` (add/remove) the entry items inside an existing playlist?

There is no edit button.

Answer (score 2):

Using the JW Player Plugin for WordPress, once a playlist has been created via the admin's playlist manager, the playlists can be edited. You just need to select your previously created playlist from the dropdown menu, and you can change the order of the items in the playlist by dragging the items around, or if you want to remove items, you can drag the items out of the playlist to the right side. If you want to add items to the playlist, they can also be dragged in.